# Why is it Charles "X Xavier" and not simply Charles "Xavier"?

Tags: character, x-men-cinematic-universe

The pronunciation of Charles' surname is "X Xavier" and not simply "Xavier". What is the reason behind it?

Comment: Because Xavier is pronounced Exavier in English

Comment: @Paulie_D well, only in X-Men: https://www.howtopronounce.com/xavier/

Comment: @StopHarmingMonica I've met two Xaviers that both pronounced it Exavier. (Granted, it was in America and one was named after Charles.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because he's the leader of the X-Men, and known as "Professor X", his name is usually pronounced emphasising the X: *ex-ay-vyer*.

Many readers are not familiar with the [correct pronunciation](https://www.howtopronounce.com/xavier/): *zay-vyer*

Comment: Why should there be a "correct pronunciation"? Same names can have different pronunciations, even in the same language (here, English), with all of them being correct pronunciations.

Comment: @Jenayah in general, there is a limited range of "correct" ways to pronounce a given word

Comment: Minor footnote to the first paragraph: it's likely a conflation between the "EX" in "Professor X" and the "Z" in "Professor (Charles) Xavier". The former pronunciation seems to have taken over the latter due to the same "Professor X..." beginning.